# unable to persist data in scope using localstorage in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using fileReader to read the file and store the image in localStorage and display it on view.

Controller:

```
angular.module('App')controller('publsherProfileEditCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', '$http', 'Auth', '$state', 'toaster', '$timeout', '$localStorage', 'operationsFactory', 'userManagementFactory', '$q', function ($rootScope, $scope, $stateParams, $location, $http, Auth, $state, toaster, $timeout, $localStorage, operationsFactory, userManagementFactory, $q) {

$scope.profilePicture = {};
var fd;
$scope.onBGSelect = function ($files) {
    var file = $files[0];
    if (!file) {
        return;
    }
    if ((/\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$/i).test(file.name)) {
        fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('content', file);
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
            return function (e) {
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    $localStorage.profilePicture = e.target.result;
                    $scope.profilePicture.content = $localStorage.profilePicture;
                });
            };
        })(file);
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    } else {
        toaster.pop('error', "File Extension", "Not allowed.");
        $('input[name="bgimage"]').val("");
    }
};
}]);
```

pushing data to server using factory:

```
$scope.publisherProfileEdit = function () {
if ($scope.profilePicture.content) {
    var track = [];
    for (var keys in $scope.profilePicture) {
        fd.append(keys, $scope.profilePicture[keys]);
    }
    track.push(operationsFactory.changeProfilePicture(fd));
    $scope.myPromise = $q.all(track).then(function (result) {
        $localStorage.profile_picture = result[0].data.profile_picture;
        console.log('success upload')
        toaster.pop('success', 'Changed Successfully');
        userManagementFactory.userProfile($localStorage.userId).success(function (response) {
            $localStorage.presentUser = response.result;
            $scope.presentUser = $localStorage.presentUser;
            $localStorage.profilePic = $scope.presentUser.profile_picture;
            $scope.profilePic = $localStorage.profilePic;
        }).error(function (error) {
            console.log('error' + error);
        });
    }, function (error) {
        console.log('error', error)
    });
};
```

Factory:

```
angular.module('App').factory('userManagementFactory', function ($http) {
    var BASEURI = 'https://www.crmmgolbale.profile/user/';
    var userProfile = function (data) {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: BASEURI + data + '/compact',
            data: data
        });
    };
    return{
        userProfile: userProfile
    };
});
```

Html view:

```
<div> 
    <img ng-src="{{profilePic}}">
        <!-- <div ng-if="profilePicture.content">
            <img ng-src="{{profilePicture.content}}"/>
        </div>-->
    <input type="file" name="bgimage" ng-file-select ng-file-change="onBGSelect($files)" ng-model="imageData" accept="" />
</div>
```

Image is uploaded properly to server but on page refresh the image data is emptied from `$scope` even after using `$localStorage`

Note: `ng-file-select ng-file-change` is directive from [ng-upload](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-file-upload)

Comment: Which method gets called for assigning `profilepic` from`localstorage` on page reload?

Comment: @Dev-One `userManagementFactory.userProfile` gets called

Comment: @Dev-One updated the question with factory method

Comment: Can you check in the browser console whether it is actually getting saved in localstorage once you upload the file?

Comment: How do you use this method from factory for assigning in controller? Bascially, does the profilepic get fetched from localStorage always or once its uploaded to server, you get path from there and assign it to profilepic?

Comment: @Chinni yes it is there in `localstorage` but some how `scope` data is deleted on refresh

Comment: Yes. So, once you refresh the page, the scope gets refreshed. Now it is your duty to populate the scope with the data in localstorage. Are you doing that in your controller? Or is it that the data is being removed from localstorage on refesh?

Comment: @Chinni I am storing the data into `scope` from `localStorage` then how come it is being deleted?

Comment: Is localstorage getting emptied on refresh? What I meant is written in the answers by Dev-One

Comment: @Chinni localStorage is not getting emptied on refresh

Comment: Perfect! Then I think you are not properly assigning the data in localstorage to scope variable once your controller loads. Check the answer written by Dev-One

Comment: @Chinni, do you think there is anything else to add to the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Whats happening is the when the file is pushed on to the server, then you refresh the page, since there is no calling method in the controller to re-assign the `$scope.profilePic`, hence it comes empty.

```
function reloadPage() {
   //You can set the picture again from storage
   $scope.profilePic = $localStorage.profilePicture

   //Or call the factory method again to repopulate it
    userManagementFactory.userProfile($localStorage.userId).success(function (response) {
        $localStorage.presentUser = response.result;
        $scope.presentUser = $localStorage.presentUser;

        //Check if profile pic already exisit
        if($scope.presentUser.profile_picture != null) {
          $localStorage.profilePic = $scope.presentUser.profile_picture;
          $scope.profilePic = $localStorage.profilePic;
        }
         //Set it back from the $localStorage
        else {
          $scope.profilePic = $localStorage.profilePic
        }
   });
}

//Run this method on page-reload as:
reloadPage();
```

PS: You have two different keys for profile Pic in `$localStorage` as `$localStorage.profilePicture` and `$localStorage.profilePic`.Make sure  use the right key for re-assigning.

Comment: Where and when should I call the `reloadPage()` method?

Comment: `$localStorage.profilePicture` is temporary image as preview before sending to server and `$localStorage.profilePic` is one from server

Comment: Somewhere you have the basic initiation method such as to get `userid`  or `userData` , there and then you can set the profilePic, or else at the end of controller would do just fine.

Comment: @Dev-One Instead of making it a scope function, it is better you make it JS function.

Comment: What I did is I added this line `$scope.profilePic = $localStorage.profilePic;` into `$stateChangeSuccess` function so that when ever state changes, the local storage will be re-assigned back into `$scope` and it worked

Comment: @Satyadev, atleast you got the idea that you had to re-assign scope from localStorage.